# Single Sign On using ADFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

We are wanting to setup SSO to multiple web applications from one central portal.

Right now we have ADFS up and running and are able to login using the public web address, A&A to AD works just fine - and we can get to a little portal we made.

What we would like to do is provide users access to specific web applications they have permissions to access (based on AD). The links would appear upon initial SSO into the portal, and the user would click a link to proceed to the web application (but would SSO into the web application).

Does anyone know how to do accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up ADFS to pass the token groups to the portal as roles using ADFS claims rules.

Then use these roles to display the appropriate links to applications.

The applications are configured as RP to ADFS.

Clicking on the link navigates to the application --> not signed in --> ADFS --> already signed in --> SSO back to application.